# A complex with homology $=R/p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Given a Noetherian ring $R$ .
I am looking for a bounded complex $X$ of finitel geenerated projectives over $R$ whose homology is $R/p$. Infact I just need $X$ to have $\operatorname{Supp}(H(X)) = \overline{p}$.

In the original paper 'The Chromatic Tower for $D(R)$'  Lemma 1.4, the author says to look at the Koszul Complex

$\bigotimes_i (R \xrightarrow{a_i} R)$  where the $\xrightarrow{a_i}$ is supposed to mean multiplication by $a_i$.  Here $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ is a set of generators for the prime ideal $p$.

However, I am unable to understand the exact meaning of this notation.
If I interpret it as $R$ tensored with itself $i$ times and the map to be $a_1 \otimes  \cdots a_n$ then it doesn't make sense to me how the homology could be $R/p$.

I read Koszul complexes from Eisenbud. I know that if $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ form a regular sequence then the standard Koszul complex has the correct homology and the homology is concentrated only in degree $n.$

However, I don't know how to get a regular sequence from a prime ideal $p$ or is it even possible to get one for Noetherian rings?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $R=k[x]/x^2$. $R$ is a local ring which is not regular (it's dimension is 0). There is no bounded complex of f.g. projectives which is quasi-isomorphic to $R/p$, $p$ being the unique prime ideal.

Comment: For a nice discussion of Koszul complexes see Eisenbud, “Commmutative Álgebra…” chapter  17

Comment: That notation is the tensor product of complexes.

Comment: In Amnon's paper, he does not claim that the tensor product of these complexes has homology $R/p$, and indeed it does not. He just claims that the support of the tensor product is the closure of $p$, which it is.

Comment: @JustinBloom how to show this? I can see that this is the same as saying that $R/p$ does not have a finite projective resolution by f.g. projectives.

Comment: Compute just one infinite resolution to show that there is nontrivial $\operatorname{Ext}^i_R(R/p,R/p)$ for each $i$. Any finite resolution would show $\operatorname{Ext}^i=0$ for large $i$,  a contradiction. But the complex $0\to R\xrightarrow{x} R\to 0$ should still have support $\{p\}$.

Comment: @DaveBenson can you help me with proving that? Is there a standard reference for this?  For example, if i take:

the version of Koszul complex as a cochain complex like:

$0 -> R -> R^n -> \wedge^2 R^n -> \cdots   -> \wedge^n R^n -> 0 -> 0 ..$

with the maps as $x \to x \wedge (a_1, \cdots a_n)$

Then I can see that the cohomology at the nth place is R/p and the 0th cohomology also has support in closure(p) but it seems difficult to compute the other cohomologies

Comment: @DaveBenson I found the proof on Wikipedia